# Future.onComplete never happens

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, callback, future

I've got what seems like  a fairly simple situation here:

1. I create a sequence of futures with `yield` of signature `Future[(String, Date)]`
2. I use `Future.sequence` to turn the `IndexedSeq[Future[(String, Date)]]` into a `Future[IndexedSeq[(String, Date)]]`
3. I call `onComplete` on that future to do something with each future after *all* of them have completed.

I'm doing this because the first wave are database inserts, I can't do the `updateCalculatedField` call until *all* inserts are completed, because `updateCalculatedField` involves aggregate functions and I don't want to introduce a race condition. Here's the code:

```
val initialInserts = for(i <- 0 until responseData.numValues()) yield { ... }
val res = Future.sequence(initialInserts)

res.onComplete{
  case Success(seq) =>
    for((i, d) <- seq)
      updateCalculatedField(i, d)
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? The code within the `onComplete` call never executes, and the program exits with no complaints. I've checked, and `res.size` is equal to the amount of rows in my database after the program exits... so the callback should have been executed. I'm at a loss here.

Thanks.

Comment: You could be exiting the program before `res` has enough time to finish. Where are you telling the program to exit?

Comment: Wow. That actually might be what's going on here. I'll check.